# Why is my json date string Invalid for date-fns?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, date-fns

I know this has been asked before. But reviewing those answers I can't figure it out. I have a Json date string `docdate: "2020-10-02T00:00:00"` that I am trying to convert to a date for display. I use System.Text.Json to serialize it in the API. I am using `date-fns` node module:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
...
<td>{format(order.docdate, 'yyyy/MM/dd')}</td>
```

... gives me this error:

```
RangeError: Invalid time value
370 | var originalDate = toDate(dirtyDate);
371 | 
372 | if (!isValid(originalDate)) {
373 |   throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
374 | } // Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.
375 | // This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.
376 | // See an issue about UTC functions: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376
```

Why is my date string Invalid?

Comment: This maybe late but you can use momentjs package too if you want to format you date to your needs something like this `moment("2020-10-02T00:00:00").format("YYYY/MM/DD")`

Comment: @MohammadKhan - momentjs hasn't been in active development since 1 OCtober 2020 (or maybe even earlier) - the documentation page suggests people use other libraries - one of which is `date-fns` - which the OP is using - so, yeah, your comment is a little late, almost a year late :p

Comment: I see thanks for telling me @Bravo, I'll try to also use other libraries from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`format` from `date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format) takes a Date object or a Number, not a string.

You should first parse the date string with either `parse` or `parseISO` from `date-fns` (giving a Date object), or the built-in [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) giving a number which can be passed to `format`.